# Setting map centre and zoom to fit all coordinates

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using google map for iOS. I have a set of coordinates. Among them I want to set one of the coordinates as the center of the map, irrespective of the zoom level. I am able to fit all the coordinates in the frame at the same time, using `GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds`. But how can I set a particular coordinate as centre all the time and also fit rest of the coordinates in the frame.

What I have tried is to create `GMSCoordinateBounds`, included all the coordinates and set fit bounds

```
[myMapview animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds withPadding:20.0f]];
```

But what I want is the map view should zoom in such a way that, this particular coordinate should be the exact centre while all other coordinates are also included in the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all map point in **GMSCoordinateBounds** using like this

```
GMSCoordinateBounds* bounds =  [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]  init  ];
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.00, 75.00);
bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:position];
```

Store all position using same type code . Adding all GMSCoordinateBounds position use with map

```
[myMapview animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds]];
//myMapview = this is object of your google map.
```

Comment: Thats what I did. But I want one particular coordinate to be the center all the time, while fitting the rest of the coordinates in the frame.

Comment: you need to store all coordinates of your map for showing here

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to create right `GMSCoordinatedBounds` object.
Say you have a number of points which you need to be fitted by map camera and the `center` point.

First you need to find the most far point from the `center`. Then calculate an extra point `far'` opposite to one you've found. It would look like this

> (far)---------(center)---------(far')

To do so just use simple `+/-` operations with latitudes and longitudes of `far` and `center` coordinates.

`Far` and `far'` will be exact two points the `bounds` required.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please see the following code. I hope it will be helpful to you

The intend is to set the boundaries of the map to focus on all the markers.
[image]

The ‘GMSMapView‘ class used to have a method ‘markers‘ which returned all the markers, but its now deprecated.
So, you will have to keep track of the markers added to the map.

Assuming that you have the following:

```
GMSMapView *mapView;
NSMutableArray *markers;
```

and all the markers are add to the NSMutableArray “markers”.

```
- (void)ShowAllMarkers
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D firstLocation = ((GMSMarker *)markers.firstObject).position;
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:firstLocation coordinate:firstLocation];

for (GMSMarker *marker in markers) {
    bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:marker.position];
}

[mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds withPadding:50.0f]];
}
```

[image]